# Xcode - Autolayout and image changing size

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, imageview, constraints

I have an application with a screen with image of a person which has auto layout constraints applied to it.

When I navigate to and from this screen, the size of that image is always changing when I inspect it but to look at it doesn't change size at all. The image shows where I have included print statements in the code to show the figure changing.

I cannot figure out why this is happening - I need to know the size of that figure at run time as other images are sized according to this size.

I really appreciate any help - this has been driving me insane for 2 days now! Let me know if there are any particular parts of code/storyboard that it would be useful to see.

[Image showing print statements of changing size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svXmB.jpg)

Comment: Please review [ask]. You need to show us what you are getting, compared to what you **want** to get, and you need to show us the constraints you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

I found that when loading the view it wasn't actually updating to be the size of the screen before I took the measurements.

Instead of taking the measurements in viewDidLoad() I used the viewDidAppear()